# the grid cell width should be resize as the text length which entered in that cell

Tags: apache-flex

In datagrid, when we are clicking on grid vertical line, the grid cell width should be resize 
as the text length which entered in that cell.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically resize a datagrid column by defining a change handler for the text component and in it changing the widht of the datagrid column. To do this, you will need to write your own item renderer for that column.

More details about flex component sizing: http://npcomplete.weebly.com/1/post/2009/10/common-sizing-issues-in-flex.html